# Access data from a chrome extension

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I have a website which is loaded using python selenium + chrome web driver for an automation purpose. A chrome extension is running which takes a particular data (say 'x') from the HTML source displays the output (say 'y') in a new tab in the chrome dev-tools.

Is there any way to access this data ('y') using python selenium + chrome web driver, so that the transformation from x->y need not be done in the python side, rather get the data directly out from the chrome extension. 
Thank You

Comment: Can you show your code where you do the transfer on the python side?

Comment: The transformation process is basically parsing through the HTML source code to convert particular set of tags to custom tags - example : when an <img> comes under a <div> it is converted to <tile> (custom tag). This is what the chrome extension does. Hence i wanted to get the converted data from the extension rather doing this in my python implementation. I don't have a code snippet for the transformation process in the python side.

Comment: So basically you want to change to the other tab with the formatted HTML?

Answer (score 1):

So I understand you have the extension that does the job and you need the already parsed HTML with your custom tags to be tested or scraped with selenium.

**The solution:**

Start with chrome options to add your extention:

```
import os
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

executable_path = "path_to_webdriver"

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_extension('path_to_extension')
```

Then start your chrome driver and go to your site:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=executable_path, chrome_options=chrome_options)
driver.get("http://your.website.com")
```

Now you need to switch to the second tab with the formatted HTML:

```
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])
```

After switching to the new tab you just go and have fun with selenium!!!

Hope this helps!